# Listing items from an array via Angular

Tags: arrays, angular

I just can't work out how to list/loop through items from an array into my component.  All the online tutorials and SO answers make sense, but my code won't respond in a like fashion.

My scenario is this: A user selects an option from a menu and...

```
  switch(which){
   :
   case 'who': {
    this.getStaffList('stafflist');
    break;
  }
  :
```

the database is called and returns an array...

```
  getStaffList(value:string){
    this.targetID = value;
    this.service.getStuff(this.targetID).subscribe(
      items => {              
        console.log(items[0].fname); <---this yields 'Sue'
        this.title = "Your staff list";
      }, error => {
      }, () => {
      } 
    );
  }
```

The PHP view of the array (before JSON.encode) is:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userID] => 6551
            [certID] => SB287
            [fname] => Sue
            [lname] => Bennett
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [userID] => 6568
        [certID] => MF6568
        [fname] => Marion
        [lname] => Ferguson
    )
 :
```

Back in Angular, the very simple template is:

```
      <div id="stafflist" class="mainbox" *ngIf="bListStaff">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">{{title}}</div>
          </div>
          <div style="padding-top:25px" class="panel-body">
             {{items[0].fname}}  <!--This generates a '..._co.items is undefined' error
            <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">{{i}} {{item}}</li> <--- this yields nothing/zilch
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The '..._co.items is undefined' error that I'm receiving suggests that the items array isn't known outside of getStaffList, but I don't understand why that is (if it is) and don't understand what's missing in my approach.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are assigning `items` to anything. Somewhere you need this.items = items;

Comment: Thanks Mark - that was the missing link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning **`items`** inside the **`subscribe`**, create a variable named **`items`** of type any and assign the value inside the subscription,

```
 getStaffList(value:string){
    this.targetID = value;
    this.service.getStuff(this.targetID).subscribe(
      items => {              
         this.items = items;
        this.title = "Your staff list";
      }, error => {
      }, () => {
      } 
    );
  }
```

also since the request is asynchronous use **`safe navigation operator`** to check if the value is present before the values are being assigned,

```
<div style="padding-top:25px" class="panel-body">
             {{items[0]?.fname}}  <!--This generates a '..._co.items is undefined' error
            <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">{{i}} {{item}}</li> <--- this yields nothing/zilch
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define a property `items` in your component class and set it like this:

```
  getStaffList(value:string){
    this.targetID = value;
    this.service.getStuff(this.targetID).subscribe(
      items => {              
        console.log(items[0].fname); <---this yields 'Sue'
        this.title = "Your staff list";
        this.items = items;
      }, error => {
      }, () => {
      } 
    );
  }
```

The scope of the items in your subscribe is only inside that function so it's not accessible from the outside.